# Excel: validating data won't force user to enter a "date formatted" data

Tags: excel, validation, date

I'm having trouble with Excel Data Validation, as it won't force users to enter a date-type data in the cell.
I'm creating a form to allow data entry from multiple paper forms.

The problem is, if a user inputs "41000" in the Date cell, it accepts the data as being the number of days since 1/1/1901 (don't know if it's absolute, it's a validation condition for me).

I want to know if there is a solution to prevent users from entering anything else than XX/XX/XXXX dates.

Thanks a bunch.

SV

Comment: Do you want **mm/dd/yyyy** or **dd/mm/yyyy?**

Comment: I'm french, so the date should be dd/mm/yyyy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is only an example that uses cells **A1** thru **A10.** 
You can adapt it to your specific layout.

The cells in **A1** thru **A10** must be first formatted to ***Text.*** Then install the following *event* macro in the worksheet area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range, r As Range, v As String, inty As Range
Dim d As Integer, m As Integer, y As Integer
Set rng = Range("A1:A10")
Set inty = Intersect(rng, Target)
If inty Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error GoTo NotGood
For Each r In inty
    v = r.Text
    ary = Split(v, "/")
    If UBound(ary) <> 2 Then GoTo NotGood
    d = CInt(ary(0))
    m = CInt(ary(1))
    y = CInt(ary(2))
    If y > 9999 Then GoTo NotGood
    If y < 1900 Then GoTo NotGood
    If m > 12 Then GoTo NotGood
    If d > 31 Then GoTo NotGood
    GoTo nxtr
NotGood:
        MsgBox "bad input in cell " & r.Address(0, 0)
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Undo
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Sub
nxtr:
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        r.ClearContents
        r.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        r.Value = DateSerial(y, m, d)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Next r
End Sub
```

The macro acts like Data Validation.  It test for some common errors and rejects them.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**